# Determine if viewcontroller is already on stack and if so, go to or dismiss it

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an app I am working on that has a main screen with two buttons.  One will take you to a view of a GPS (map) and then once there (new VC) it has options for setting that position or bringing up a list (tableview, another VC) of all locations already tagged.

At the list VC, if you click on the table cell, it will bring up the VC with the map.  Problem is, this then adds the same VC bak on the stack.  If a user clicks the Cancel button, they go back ones screen, then cancel goes back another screen, etc... until back to the main.

I know I can do the [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; to pop back to root but that is not always what I want.

Also, I know I can do:  [[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

I guess what I am saying is I want to "reuse" the GPS map view so I can call it from other VC's, so that is why I didn't go with the "pass back" to calling VC.  So, is there away to either when a button is pressed and is to present a new VC, can I dismiss the prior one after the new one is shown?  This way, a dismiss of current VC would take me back to where I need to be.

I hope makes sense and also that this question doesn't fall into the "Not an actual question" category.

Any help or better suggestions is greatly appreciated.  Thx

Geo...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump back some number of levels in a navigation controller's VC stack, you'll probably want to use its [`popToViewController:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController%3aanimated%3a) method. To figure out if a particular view controller is on that stack, look at the navigation controller's [`viewControllers`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property. Be careful, though, as this kind of jumping around is a rather nonstandard UI behavior (even though there's API for it) which might confuse your users.

Also, using navigation controllers and presenting modally aren't the only ways to manage multiple view controllers -- you can always set the window's `rootViewController` yourself (and animate the change with UIView animations), even wrapping up your custom transition type in a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a delegate in the table view. So that when a cell is pressed the info is passed to the delegate method in the VC which will dismiss the table view and reloads itself with the new info. You will have to implement refresh method in that VC.